# Asp.Net Tag Helper type="date" allows more than 4 digits for Year

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, html-helper

I am using the asp.net core tag helper input type="date" and it allows me to type in more than 4 digits for my year.  I have tried setting the Display format but i am still allowed to type more than 4 digits for the year resulting in a year that doesn't make sense.

```
<input asp-for="@Model.BirthDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" class="form-control" type="date" required="">
```

where BirthDate is defined in my Model as follows:

```
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

and, yes, I did try changing BirthDate to not be nullable.

I am allowed to type the following in the Input field:  **08/01/2001999999** which results in the input displaying the following:  **08/01/275760**.  Is there a way to force the tag helper to only allow 4 digits for the year?

Answer (score 0):

You should use - the format would certainly depend on the format you want user to input the value.

```
asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
```

Also add below attribute on Model property

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Hope this works.